# eclipse override method

Tags: eclipse

I have downloaded eclipse Galileo.

Now, when I use actionListener for the button, it would preferred for override an `onClick` method of that listener, but in my Eclipse, it doesn't display the `@override` heading on the `onClick` method.

Do you have any clue about that missing annotation?

Comment: Are you using JDK5 or 6 with your project?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of bugs regarding the @override annotation not being displayed:

- [bug 293777](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=293777): Misleading problem when @Override is used on method with unresolved parameter type
- [bug 235750](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=235750): [clean up] 'Save Actions' doesn't add override annotation for interface method implementations (Java6)

Could you check if your particular problems persists with Eclipse Helios (3.6)?